# Getting different Json Array element Order in Retrofit and Postman

Tags: android, retrofit2, postman

I hit same API from Postman & Retrofit. Postman returns correct JSON array elements order but in Retrofit i get shuffled results.

I am expecting the same JSON array element order in retrofit as i get in postman.

> **POSTMAN parameters**

```
{
"campusId":1,
"reported":true,
"size":30,
"status":[5,6,7,8],
"sortBy":"updatedAt",
"sortDirection":"desc",
"page":1
}
```

**Retrofit Parameters**

```
    Map<String,Object> body = new HashMap<>();
    body.put("campusId",1);
    body.put("reported",true);
    body.put("size",30);
    body.put("status", Arrays.asList(5,6,7,8));
    body.put("sortBy ","updatedAt");
    body.put("sortDirection","desc"); //desc
    body.put("page",1);
```

Comment: are you sure that it is the JSONArray? Not just object with fields? If yes, then it is the backend (server) who decides the order. You probably using something different in requests via retrofit and postman

Comment: @Shane, according to the official JSON documentation, you are 100% wrong: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt

Comment: @Shane `An array is an ordered sequence of zero or more values.`

Comment: @ Vladyslav Matviienko, Thank you for commenting on issue, Yes it is json array and i get expected order (descending) in response from server in postman but when i try to get it in android application using retrofit, i get shuffled json array elements.

Comment: `You probably using something different in requests via retrofit and postman`. Retrofit has nothing to do with orderring

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko, I have updated my question & given the parameters i passed in postman & retrofit.

Comment: You only posted the input, and not the output? (to show that they are different)

Comment: Use JSONObject instead of HashMap, this will help you out

Comment: Is it a GET or a POST request? And how are you passing this Map to Retrofit?

Comment: Can you post server codes returning json response?

Comment: @ Philippe A, Thank you for commenting, this is a POST request and passing hashmap in request body by using "@Body" annotation.

Comment: @faranjit, Getting 200 status code

Comment: Sorry bro, i mean your backend code. Maybe there is a trick.

Comment: just to make sure, you mean the field `status` has a different order? Because the actual json you posted, if the keys are in a different order, than that's totally fine and defined by the json spec - dicts don't have an order.